# Connection between JasperStudio and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, jdbc, mongodb-query, jaspersoft-studio

I tried connecting mongodb to Japerstudio using the MongoDb connection option and the JDBC Option by following some tutorials. The MongoDB option is not even able to connect to the Database using the connection string. The JDBC Option is not able to recognize the JDBC Driver, I even added the JDBC jar file to Libraries accordingly.
Can someone guide me to the detail, how to make a stable connection between mongodb and JasperStudio?

Finally, I somehow able to connect to my local mongodb and tried to make reports on data using queries. The queries i am performing are sometimes not even accepted and sometimes even though they are accepted, It is only showing reports by pasting raw data over the pages and not helping in anyway by making the data usable to work (like making charts,graphs,etc). when i accessed the data i tried to add some fields in mongodb to the chart, but it is only able to add it in json format and unable to make it a good visual representation.

Example:

```
{
    'collectionName':'Employee',
    'findFields':{
    'details': {
      $elemMatch: {
        'department': 'IT',
        'subdept": "software",
        'leave_period': {
          $gte:"2023-08-05T09:00:00Z",
          $lte:"2023-08-10T20:00:00Z"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

if i use the above query, i expect it to show the results between given dates. but it is not showing any data at all.
can someone guide me how to even do this, if that is possible?

Comment: Are you sure the issue is due to connection between mongodb and jasper? Have you tried inputting the query into the mongo shell independently to see whether it can get any data? For a quick look, the date query might not work since you could be matching date strings to date fields.

Comment: @Jay, same connecttion query works in mongo compass.

Answer (score -1):

You need to allowlist the IPs for the JasperStrudio. Find the IPs and add the same in this way

[image]

Comment: Infact the mongo is not Atlas, but entrprice edition deployed in azure running as a pod, the connection string used can be connected to mongo compass successfully but fails in jasper. URI looks like this  `mongodb://xx.xx.xxx.xx:27017/?authSource=product-db&readPreference=primary&directConnection=true&tls=true&tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=true/product-db` , error is `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: databaseName can not be null` even though the database name(product-db) is added at the end

Comment: Your database name should go here: `mongodb://xx.xx.xxx.xx:2701/<database_name>?the_rest_of_the_params` not at the end. Try that and let me know.

Comment: now the new exception after trying above suggestion is - `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error creating MongoDBConnection; Caused by: Cannot test MongoDB connection; Caused by: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN,, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target}`

Comment: Can you give me the updated uri?

Comment: here it is - `mongodb://xx.xx.xxx.xx:27017/product-db?authSource=product-db&readPreference=primary&directConnection=true&tls=true&tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=true`